# Apache tomcat throwing 404 error on ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, tomcat, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache tomcat jQuery Ajax returning 404 if sent too quicklyt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484045/apache-tomcat-jquery-ajax-returning-404-if-sent-too-quicklyt)

Only throwing error when made too quickly after a page request or another ajax call,
Does anyone know what could be causing this? If I whip a timeout before it it always succeeds, are there any things in Apache Tomcat that relate to minimum request time or such?

Comment: Please don't repost your questions if they get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
are there any things in Apache Tomcat that relate to minimum request time or such?
```

No.

You need to look in your Apache log file for what URL you are requesting that is not being found.

I suspect it will be some synchronization issue with your Javascript which is causing a bad request.